# How to export ABAP package objects metadata?

Tags: abap, s4hana

I want to export package structure including all the objects, types, classes and programs with their metadata. I want to keep object metadata and all their relations including subpackage hierarchy relation, program/include relation, FM/include/master program relation, etc.

[image]

Ideally it should be resembling SE80 hierarchy output, I want it formatted in Excel.

I tried:

1. Display - UML Class Diagram. That gives something weird not very useful

[image]

2. Display - Object List. Shows only use accesses, interfaces and subpackages, but not the full object list.
3. Package check - All Object. It shows only errors, also not useful.

I know this is something that was not possible in classic ECC by built-in tools, but maybe we have something nicey in S4?

I am on S4HANA 1709.

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing the context or which metadata you are looking for but have you considered getting the objects from the TADIR table? You can easily filter the artifacts based on the `devclass` (package) column.

Comment: `which metadata` object names and descriptions. And their relations, of course, this is the most critical piece. I need to know which classes belong to which package, which includes belongs to which programs, which methods are in which classes and et cetera

Comment: `have you considered getting the objects from the TADIR table?` yes, I did, and that is what I am doing right now. However, this is not a straighforward way and I spend a lot for time formatting TADIR output and finding relationships with multelevel nested objects.

Comment: so is it a combo of TADIR and the ABAP Cross-ref info youre after ?

Comment: `so is it a combo of TADIR and the ABAP Cross-ref` kind of

Answer (score -1):

If you want to export packages and sub packages and all the development objects and take them with you to another SAP system, the best way is with a transport.

Create a Transport in Se10.
A transport of copies is ideal here.
Then in se80
write all the objects of a DEV class to a transport.
Use the function,
right click, write transport entry

[image: Add to transport]

Then select the all objects button

[image: Select all objects]

Note you will need to repeat this for sub packages.
This feature does not traverse sub packages automatically.

Then release your transport.

Now simply pickup the transport files and important to the next system

Comment: `If you want to export packages` no, I am not. I am aware to how to transport objects and packages, I need objects' metadata purely for documentation purposes

Comment: Sorry I only noticed now the post was from You with the comment.
Please excuse the patronising response. Of course you know that.   Sorry.